# What is my LDAP Connection String

Tags: windows, ldap

Are there any tools that tell you what your LDAP connection string is?

Comment: @ferronrsmith Maybe you should edit your question to specify that you want the connection strings for the LDAP servers on your active directory. You ask an important question that would get voted up and have more answers if better asked.

Comment: @justin nevermind, figured it out myself thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tool called Softerra ldap browser that I used when I was first messing around with ldap on windows.

It connected something like this ldap://domaincontrollername:port/  and used my network credentials.

I also have done a little in .net with it and have had similar strings to connect and also using ldap://DC=domainname and if your domain name is something like here.there then ldap://dc=here,dc=there

Comment: how do i supply the username and password of the ldap server within the connection string

Comment: That's a good question.  I actually haven't done that in .Net as I was using windows authentication to authenticate me.  However, take a look at this article:
http://forums.asp.net/p/1021956/1385081.aspx
It has a sample function to authenticate a user.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the following VBScript on the Server.

```
    Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
objSysInfo.RefreshSchemaCache
WScript.Echo "User name: " & objSysInfo.UserName
```

Copy all of the DCs displayed in the dialog box and use that as your LDAP connection string following LDAP://

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for examples of how to set one up?

http://www.connectionstrings.com/ should help if that's the case.

Comment: Assuming @ferronrsmith means An active directory string: http://www.connectionstrings.com/active-directory

Comment: yes its for AD. I'm trying to import users into a view in sql server, but i don't know the current LDAP settings

Comment: like LDAP://YourLDAPServer ?? what am i suppose to add and how can i get this information from AD

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean what is the name of the LDAP servers for your active directory domain? Then you want to use SRV records. Assuming your active directory base domain is foo.com you want to look up the SRV record of _ldap_tcp.foo.com see [this technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738991.aspx)